# How to plot contour of a covariance matrix of a gaussian distribution?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I just want to ask how you can plot the contour of covariance of a Gaussian, say covariance of `[513.5211 -160.7084; -160.7084 808.8846]`.

For example

[image: This]

The gaussian points are red and the covariance is represented by the blue dotted circle. How can I plot the plot dotted circle (covariance matrix) in Matlab?.

**EDIT**

Here is what I have done

```
Sigma = Cov(X);
Contour(Sigma);
```

Any idea?

Comment: @DangKhoa, please see Edit for wjat i was trying.

Comment: i am trying to use the example here: http://statlearn.free.fr/doc/Multidimensional%20distribution%20tutorial.htm, but g = gaussdens('m',[1;2],'var',[4 1;1 2]); does not exist in mt matlab version(Ver R2008b). The show(g) also does not work. Any idea of any function that does this job in matlab?

Comment: I think `gaussdens` is a function of the 3rd-party toolbox [`statlearn`](http://statlearn.free.fr/). Do you have that toolbox?

Comment: @Schorsch, No i don't have the gaussdens toolbox.

Comment: Have you tried downloading and using the [`statlearn`](http://statlearn.free.fr/index.html) toolbox?

Comment: @Schorsch, i have used a different third party function and it is working for me now. I just have one issue, in my program, i generate population initially using rand and for each iteration of my loop, i select top 25% of the population. I plot both the Generated Population and selected individuals for each run of the algorithm, but each time i look at the positions of the selected individuals on their plot and their position in the plot of the initial generated population, they are different, when their positions should be the same. I don't know why. Any idea why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I finally did what i wanted to do by using a third party function called [`plot_gaussian_ellipsoid`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16543-plotgaussianellipsoid) from the Matlab Central FileExchange.
It plots the contour of the covariance matrix.